# How to disable direct Firebase CLI deploys and only allow deploys via Github Actions?

Tags: firebase

I have a Firebase app.

Now I want to setup a CI pipeline.

Since the repo is hosted on Github I setup a Github Action so that it deploys the site to Firebase on merge. Eventually I will add tests and other stuff to this pipeline.

Now considering I always want the deploys to run through the CI pipeline on Github, can I instruct Firebase to only accept deploys from the Github Action and not from a direct `firebase deploy` command on my (or someone else's) local machine?